# Laravel Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefrompng()

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, php-glide

Hi I am using glide (http://glide.thephpleague.com/) for image manipulation in my `laravel` project.
I am facing an issue when storing an Image. 
"Call to undefined function `Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefrompng()`"

The strange thing is that I can open the image with "preview" on my mac. But not in the browser. Also Photoshop tells me that there is something wrong with this file, it's corrupt.

this is how I save the image in a private folder:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

  //Show the image
  echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';

  //Get the base-64 string from data
  $filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

  //Decode the string
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

  //Save the image
  $storagepath = storage_path('app/images/users/' . Auth::user()->id);
  $imgoutput = File::put($storagepath.'/flyer.jpg', $unencodedData);

  return view('backend.flyers.index')->withImgoutput($imgoutput);
                                     //->withStoragepath($storagepath);

}
```

It seems like File::put(XXX.**jpg**) **JPG** causes the problem.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `GD Library` is missing. Try this:

You must enable the library GD2.

Find your (proper) `php.ini` file

Find the line: `;extension=php_gd2.dll` and remove the semicolon in the front.

The line should look like this:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Then restart apache and you should be good to go.

Comment: with php --ini I am getting this error mesage: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Library is missing, install it

Comment: By the way. I am on a mac, aren't .dll files only for windows?

Comment: Yes, .dll files are only supposed to be for windows. For a mac machine, you can install gd library using homebrew and manuallly add an extension to the php.ini file